# Nodes taken from pandas Dataframe is not fully connected by NetworkX

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have a dataframe of that I use to calculate the weight of distribution between OS and limit.

```
| customer_id |  limit_reference   |   OS   |  limit  |

| ----------- | ------------------ | ------ | ------- |

|    1111     | 1111.A.1::1111.B.1 |   0.1  |    5    |

|    1111     | 1111.A.1           |   .08  |    5    |

|    9012     | 1111.B.1::9012.B.1 |   .15  |    5    |
```

The value in `limit_reference` is of the form: `ID.contract_reference`.
I need to match all value in `customer_id` and `limit_reference`, and group them into groups. So if I created another `group_id` column, then I will have:

```
| customer_id |  limit_reference   |   OS   |  limit  | group_id |

| ----------- | ------------------ | ------ | ------- | ---------|

|    1111     | 1111.A.1::1111.B.1 |   0.1  |    5    |    1     |

|    1111     | 1111.A.1           |   .08  |    5    |    1     |

|    9012     | 1111.B.1::9012.B.1 |   .15  |    5    |    1     |
```

The problem I have is `networkx` recognize `1111.A.1::1111.B.1` and `1111.B.1::9012.B.1` as 2 different nodes even though they have the same element `1111.B.1`.

I have tried to split `limit_reference`, but it is unhashable. Here's the code I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df_ = pd.read_excel('sample2.xlsx')

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_, 'customer_id', 'limit_reference')
cnc = nx.connected_components(G)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, scale=20, k=2/np.sqrt(G.order()))
df_['group_id'] = [label for node in df_.customer_id for label, component in lookup.items() if node in component]

nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=1000, with_labels=True)
lookup = {i: component for i, component in enumerate(cnc, 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `limit_reference` with pandas' `Series.str.split()` method, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id': [1111, 1111, 9012],
                    'limit_reference': ['1111.A.1::1111.B.1', 
                                        '1111.A.1', 
                                        '1111.B.1::9012.B.1']})   
G = nx.Graph()

limit_reference_split = [x for sublist in df_['limit_reference'].str.split('::') 
                           for x in sublist]
G.add_nodes_from(limit_reference_split)

list(G.nodes)
```

```
['1111.A.1', '1111.B.1', '9012.B.1']
```